# AS3 TypedDictionary?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

```
 public dynamic class TypedDictionary extends Dictionary {
    private var _type:Class;

    public function TypedDictionary(type:Class, weakKeys:Boolean = false) {
        _type = type;
        super(weakKeys);
    }

    public function addValue(key:Object, value:_type):void {
        this[key] = value;
    }

    public function getValue(key:Object):_type{
        return this[key];
    }
...
```

I want to make TypedDictionary with typisation. But I can not use `_type` in `addValue` and `getValue`. The idea is to use next construction :

```
var td:TypedDictionary = new TypedDictionary(myClass, true);
td.addValue("first", new myClass());
...
var item:myClass = td.getValue("first");
item.someFunction();
```

Is any ability to use dynamic class type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I un derstand what you are asking for.
This is untested code so it could be error prone, but it should get you on the right path.

```
 public dynamic class TypedDictionary extends Dictionary {
    private var _type:Class;

    public function TypedDictionary(type:String, weakKeys:Boolean = false) {
        _type =  getDefinitionByName(type) as Class;
        super(weakKeys);
    }

    public function addValue(key:Object, value:*):void {
        if(_type == getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(value))){
            this[key] = value;
        }else{
            trace('failed type match')
        }
    }

    public function getValue(key:Object):*{
        return this[key];
    }
...


var td:TypedDictionary = new TypedDictionary("com.somepackage.myClass", true);
td.addValue("first", new myClass());

var item:myClass = td.getValue("first");
item.someFunction();
```

Comment: Interesting. What about getValue(key:Object):`_type` ?

Comment: Ah I missed that. All fixed now